# Paradigm for handling references to parents (or functional global data) in Java - Example

Tags: java

I have 3 classes instantiated with unknown property values. Each class serves as  a property of the one before it. I'm looking for the best way to access the `Top` object from a method in the bottom object.

```
public class Top {
  private List<Middle> middle;

  public int getMiddleSize() {
    return this.middle.size();
  }
}

public class Middle {
  private List<Bottom> bottom;
}

public class Bottom {
  private String name;

  //Access Top.getMiddleSize() here
}
```

Should I just pass the `Top` object all the way down to the bottom, or is there a good way to make the `Top` object accessible globally?

Comment: I just accidentally hit enter before I finished.

Comment: your bottom class has no chance to get a reference to the top class. You can maybe create a reference yourself with a `HashMap<Top, List<Bottom>>` inside of the Middle Class. Don't know if that would be a good implementation